# fviz_pca_ind () Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : ICU init failed: U_FILE_ACCESS_ERROR

Tags: r, pca

My code is

```
library(stats)
library(ggplot2)
library(factoextra)

data <- structure(list(X346.2 = c(10.55363429, 15.03619168, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9.133031437, 0, 17.73382806, 0.951441625),
  X346.42 = c(8.066986667, 14.45424883, 3.962592593, 3.170740741, 3.889703704, 5.333185185, 10.59940181, 2.778592593, 15.66671695, 1.394182366)), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c("pinus 1", "pinus 2", "pinus 3", 
"pinus 4", "pinus 5", "pinus 6", "pinus 7", "pinus 8", "olea 1", "olea 2"))


pc <- prcomp(x = data,rank=6,scale. = TRUE)
fviz_pca_ind(pc, geom.ind = "point", pointshape = 21, 
            pointsize = 2, 
            col.ind = "black", 
            palette = "jco", 
            addEllipses = TRUE,
            label = "var",
            col.var = "black",
            repel = TRUE,
            legend.title = "Pollendust") +
  ggtitle("PCA") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

I have called many different libaries.
I have changed my code for the `fviz_pca_ind()` but it gives me the same error

> Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) :    ICU
> init failed: U_FILE_ACCESS_ERROR

The prcomp() gives the right results
My data is a data frame 10obs. of 1736 variables
Can anyone help with that?

Comment: can you post some data so we could reproduce the problem. after loading the file use `dput(data)`

Comment: I run it on R studio as administartor, i use the R version 4.0.2

Comment: I'm asking about the data u used in `pcrcomp`

Comment: I can't reproduce the error with just these two variables :(

Comment: file.io link is not working

Comment: this link is broken too :(

Comment: It's frustrating tbh :(